# i get this ' Property 'matches' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.' on angular-cli output

Tags: angular, typescript, events, angular-cli

but the code is doing the job with no error on chrome console

```
 constructor() {
    window.onclick = (event: MouseEvent) => {
      if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
        const dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-content');
        let i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
          const openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
          if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
            openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
          }
        }
      }
    };
  }
```

something with typescript i assume.. anyone had it?

Answer (score 2):

change the events type for a quick fix:

```
window.onclick = (event: any) => {
```

You could also use type assertions to tell the compiler that it is ok:

```
window.onclick = (event: MouseEvent) => {
  const event_cast_type = event as any;
  if (!event_cast_type.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
```

But remember type assertions are as dangerous as using any since you are telling the compiler you know more about types than it does. However for this case I think it is the only way to pass this issue since a type assertion will kill the problem at its root which is the compiler.